# Do not install core when installing modules with composer

Tags: composer

I want to manage my modules with composer, so I created a *composer.json* file in my *sites/my_site* directory that looks like this:

```
{
    "repositories": {
        "drupal": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "~1.0",
        "drupal/addtoany": "^1.8",
        "drupal/workbench": "^1.0",
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
            "modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
            "themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run "composer install" or "composer update", I get a "**core**" directory with Drupal core created in my *sites/my_site* directory. Is there any way to avoid pulling in the core and only get the modules using composer from my *sites/my_site* directory?

Comment: Shouldn't composer be in the root directory?

Comment: It should. In my case though I am using a shared Drupal install and only have permissions to my *sites/my_site* directory, so want to manage the dependencies from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not try this personally, but should work. Add this to your composer.json root:

`"name": "drupal/core",
 "version": "8.4.2",`

(adjust version number to your installed core version)

Be aware though this is not considered a clean solution, the recommended way is for drupal composer is "all or nothing". And I really recommend the "all" way, you do get the comfort of dependency *and* version *and* patch management.

More info about this hack: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5024

Comment: Tried that, but for some reason it now fails claiming that drupal/core dependency is missing: 
Problem 1
    - drupal/migrate_source_csv 2.0.0 requires drupal/core ~8.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.1.0, 8.1.0-beta1, ...]

Comment: Looks like adding version made it work:
"version": "8.4.2",